# What is the recommended method of storing EJB configuration? (Java version of app.config/web.config)

Tags: java, configuration, ejb, web.xml

I must apologize for asking what was probably asked numerous times before, but after extensive search I still am not sure.

web.xml can store configuration parameters for the JSP pages and servlets. Can that be used for the bean in the same project? Otherwise is there anything similar for the beans?

The items I am looking to store would be deployment-specific strings: DB driver class, connection string and a bunch of paths to the resources.

One of the options I came across was java.util.Properties, however it would require some coding.

**EDIT:**

To implement the below proposed solutions I've added ejb-jar.xml to the bean project and populated it with following:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>ejbConfigurator</ejb-name>
        <env-entry>
            <description>Path to the directory containing images</description>
            <!--env-entry-name>package.ejbConfigurator/imageBasePath</env-entry-name-->
            <env-entry-name>imageBasePath</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>/home/user/NetBeansProjects/Builder/images</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

The annotated variables did not get populated:

```
@Resource(name="imageBasePath")
private String imageBasePath;
```

or

```
@Resource private String imageBasePath;
```

And the code below

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    this.imageBasePath = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/imageBasePath");
}
catch (NamingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ejbBlanketConfigurator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

threw an exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/imageBasePath
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways and depending on what's your deployment structure it may make sense to pick one or another.

- `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` - this is used when the EJBs are inside their own JAR which in turn is part of an EAR.
- `WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml` - this is used when EJBs are part of a WAR.
- annotations - many configuration options can be specified through annotations on the bean class itself.

The above are configurations specific to EJBs. However, some of the resources you mention may be specified in both `ejb-jar.xml` and `web.xml`.

For reference, try reading the [schema file](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/.../ejb-jar_3_0.xsd%E2%80%8E) - it's fairly well documented, or something like [this](http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3/reference-for-ejb-jar-xml/).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `ejb-jar.xml` and in particular the `env-entry` element, which allows you to inject configured items into your code

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>some_name</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>Some configurable value</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

and to use it with annotations:

```
@Resource(name="some_name")
String someString;
```

See http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/env_entry/env_entry.html

As another has posted, the location of the ejb-jar.xml matters depending on where your EJB jar is located.

HOWEVER

When it comes to DB driver classes and connection strings specifically, you may want to look into externally configuring datasources and then accessing the externally configured datasource from your application (via JNDI or JNDI + resource-refs usually).

Comment: Tried to follow your answer and linked tutorial, but there is an issue: the variables, injected by way of @Resource annotation are null. This project's EJB is under EAR and therefore ejb-jar.xml fell under META-INF. Added a bunch of env-entries of type java.lang.String and none of them injected anything. Tried with and without name qualifier in Resource annotation, with and without fully qualified package/class/field name and result is the same - variables are null.

Comment: Just now implemented @PostConstruct init method, but control never entered it. Tried moving context lookup into the constructor and got an exception 'No object bound to name...'

Comment: Are you sure that you are running this code in a JEE container?

Comment: NetBeans runs it in GlassFish if I am getting your question correctly

Comment: Your deployment is mis-configured somewhere. This method will do what you asked if your JEE configuration is correct, but solving that problem is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: NetBeans deployed ejb-jar.xml under both /home/user/NetBeansProjects/Builder/dist/Builder.ear/Builder-ejb.jar/META-INF/ and /home/user/NetBeansProjects/Builder/dist/gfdeploy/Builder/Builder-ejb_jar/META-INF/ Are those correct locations? Just experimenting, I tried placing it under WEB-INF too, but project failed to deploy/run then.